Detect a variable change in React
I am trying to detect a variable change in React. The variable is a class property. That is set when an asynchronous event takes place.
You can see below the example of my class.
Inside method listenForIncomingMessage(), something asynchronous happens and it sets the data property of the class.
class Message() {
  static #instance: Message;
  data!: any;

  static getInstance(): Message {
    if (!Message.#instance) {
      Message.#instance = new Message();
    }

    return Message.#instance;
  }
  
  listenForIncomingMessage() {

    // Something asynchronous is happening here
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.data = 'hello world';
    }, 2000);
  }
}

Then this class is initialized in main.tsx like this and it is passed through a prop like this
const MainPage = () => {
  const msg = Message.getInstance();
  msg.listenForIncomingMessage();

  return (
    <div className="panel">
      <Result message={ msg } />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLDivElement,
).render(<MainPage />);

Finally inside Result.tsx, I need to detect the latest value for msg.data.
export default function Result({ msg }) {
  let responseObj = useRef(msg.data);

  useEffect(() => {             <------ This is not triggered
    console.log(msg.data); 
  }, [msg.data]);

)};

I could get the value from a callback, or event listener inside Result.tsx but I am trying to see if there is a React hook solution.

Changes to an object property are not tracked by React, and don't cause it re-render the parent and children.
You can wrap the instance in Proxy with a set() handler to catch changes to the data property, and set a state accordingly.
In addition, since listening to external events is a side effect, this should happen  inside a useEffect block. This will prevent an infinite loop of trigger listen -> set state -> re-render -> trigger listen -> ...
const MainPage = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const msg = new Proxy(Message.getInstance(), {
      set(target, key, value) {
          target[key] = value;
          
          // update the component's state only if the key is data
          if(key === 'data') setMessage(value);
          
          return true;
      }
    });

    msg.listenForIncomingMessage();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="panel">
      <Result message={message} />
    </div>
  );
};

 const Result = ({ message }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(message); 
  }, [message]);

)};

If you need to use the proxied instance for other things, you can wrap it in useMemo. The listen to changes, however, still needs to happen inside useEffect:
const MainPage = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  
  const msg = useMemo(() => new Proxy(Message.getInstance(), {
    set(target, key, value) {
        target[key] = value;

        // update the component's state only if the key is data
        if(key === 'data') setMessage(value);

        return true;
    }
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    msg.listenForIncomingMessage();
  }, [msg]);

  return (
    <div className="panel">
      <Result message={message} />
    </div>
  );
};


Thank you for your answer. It worked as expected. If I needed to force update on any changes in the class (not only data), How can this be achieved ?
The objective has changed and I need to pass the whole class inside  component with updated values.

Just remove the condition in this line if(key === 'data') setMessage(value); and set a copy of Message.getInstace, or replace the condition with something that fits the changes that you want to track.
